# How to insert figure from my pc to Mathematica SE

Tags: discussion, formatting

How to upload figure from my pc to Mathematica SE ?

On Mathematica SE editor there is a panel called figure, put it describes how to upload figure from a website ..

So any help

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Also consider the [SE-Uploader](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1521/1063).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the editor's text-input panel

1. Put the cursor where you want the image to appear in your post.
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to get a drag-and-drop image drop panel.
3. Drag a PNG image into the drop panel.
4. Click on Add Picture at the lower-right of the drop panel.

Here is an image that I loaded into this post by the method described above:

[image]

Comment: It's easy :) thanx